# How do I know if I should create an Non clustered Index on a Clustered Index or on a heap?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-performance

I have a DB containing some tables, no table has non-clustered index defined. The big application which uses this DB is slow(because the number of rows are close to a million). I want to optimize DB fetch operations by adding indexes. When I read about indexes I came across index names like:

- Clustered Index
- Non clustered Index on a Clustered Index
- Non Clustered Index on a heap

Also, indexes need to be created only on some columns. How will I identify that in a table which kind of index need to be created and across which column(s)?

**P.S.** Execution plan while running query tells to create NCI on all columns. Can I blindly go ahead and create index as suggested by SQL Server?

Comment: refer this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56/how-to-determine-if-an-index-is-required-or-necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **clustered index** is a type of index which defines how the data of your table will be stored (more precisely, *how the data is sorted*). This is the reason why the clustered index columns should be chosen very carefully (sequentially inserted data is primordial or you will end up with fragmentation and performance issues over time, an integer "identity" column is a good pick for example).
I found out that it is a good practice to always have a clustered index on your permanent tables.

**A table without a clustered index is a heap** because data is not sorted in a particular way (it'll be added at the end of the file), data is therefore harder to retrieve. The only improvement you can get from using a heap without indexes is that data insertion will be faster.

A **non-clustered index** is a separate file that will help speed up your queries on the columns you choose (it will store values of the indexed data and their reference to the location in the main file). As the data of your table become more and more important, having those separate files can dramatically improve the performance of your queries because the db engine won't have to scan the entire table for the data you are looking for, but just look for the position of the rows to retrieve in the index file (which contains ordered data of the columns you've chosen). 
Adding indexes will speed up your select queries, but slow down writing operations as the indexes have to be updated. **So, don't create too many indexes on too many columns !**

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of tables: heap tables (which have no clustered index) and clustered tables (which do). Each of these can have any number of non-clustered indexes built on them.

When do you use a heap table? Realistically, in only one scenario: when you're doing parallel bulk imports. This specific scenario requires that the table have no clustered index. In all other scenarios, a heap table has worse performance than a table with a clustered index -- don't take my word for it, though: Microsoft has an [article on this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917672.aspx) that, while dated, is still relevant. In other words, for most practical database work, you can ignore heap tables as a curiosity.

On what do you create your clustered index? Ideally, on a column with values that are ever increasing (or decreasing) and aren't changed in updates. Why? Because this has the least overhead for updating, as no data has to be moved. Because of these two requirements, surrogate keys in the form of `IDENTITY` columns are popular, since they neatly meet them. This is certainly not the only possible choice, though: indexing on an ever increasing timestamp is also popular (in big data warehouses, for example).

With that (mostly) out of the way, how do you decide what other columns to index? Now that's a great question, but not one I feel qualified to answer in all its glory here. I've gotten a lot of experience myself with index design over the years, but I'm not aware of specific books or articles that I could recommend (which is not to say they don't exist, and I hope other people can chime in with suggestions). For what it's worth, Microsoft itself has [written a guide here](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj835095), which is quite in-depth (perhaps too much so), but I haven't thoroughly read this myself.

Can you blindly go ahead and create the indexes as suggested by the query optimizer? If by that you mean "should I", then the answer is almost certainly no. The query optimizer is very eager to suggest and and all possible indexes that could speed up a query, but that doesn't mean they should all be created -- every index increases the overhead of performing inserts and updates on the table. If you followed the optimizer's advice, it's probable that you would eventually end up with indexes covering every possible combination of columns, which would be pretty terrible for anything that's not a `SELECT` query. Having said that, creating too many indexes is almost always not as awful as creating no indexes at all, since that quickly kills performance for most queries that involve tables with more than about 10.000 rows.

I could write books on this topic, but I haven't the time or (I fear) the skill. I hope this at least gets you started.